# how many selected rows at maximum can be inserted in a table in mysql in one insert statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using this statement to copy the data of one table to another where both these tables are identical,

```
INSERT INTO summary_table SELECT * FROM wallet_transaction WHERE type_id = 1;
```

the number of rows selected from 'wallet_transaction' could be in lakhs someday, I want to know whether this query can be successful in doing this and is there any limit of rows that can be inserted after selection ?

Comment: There is no any restriction in your case. Except the query may take too much time with "lost connection" error - so adjust timeouts. *the number of rows .. could be in lakhs* This is somewhere between "few" and "little".

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not understood globally, and use words like *million* or *thousand* instead